# Stumped at a simple segmentation fault. C++

Tags: c++

Could somebody be kind to explain why in the world this gives me a segmentation fault error?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <double>freqnote;

int main(){

freqnote[0] = 16.35;

cout << freqnote[0];

return 0;
}
```

I had other vectors in the code and this is the only vector that seems to be giving me trouble.

I changed it to `vector<int>freqnote;` and changed the value to 16 and I STILL get the segmentation fault. What is going on?

I have other vector ints and they give me correct results.

Comment: Dude!!..you need to revise your skills on inserting elements into a vector.Vectors are not same as arrays in c.

Comment: If it is VS2010, it gives a clear error message in debug mode about the subscript being out of range

Comment: Why would you think that changing int to double would eliminate the segmentation fault?

Comment: Because I had other <int> vectors that worked just fine without actually having to specify the size and I didn't get why it worked as int but not double at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing vector out of bounds. First you need to initialize vector specifying it's size.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v(10);
    v[0] = 10;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how other vectors haven't given me any issues without specifying the size?

Also, I had a long vector (0-107 vectors) specified size of 108 and STILL Got a segmentation fault. What's going on?

Comment: You may have used them in a different context. For example you may have added elements using push_back, or insert functions. If you give the actual code example, then I'd be able to comment. Segmentation fault also may have been for a completely different reason.

Comment: You should not really be declaring elements like that, its much better to use the push_back() syntax.

Comment: Tomas, I don't agree as this depends on the context of your code very much. One good reason not to use push_back is that it increases a constant factor. I.e. it is cheaper to initialize 10 elements, then do push_back on 10 elements, as vector doubles it's size when there is not enough space, and makes calls to malloc (unless you overrode memory allocators), which is expensive -- and you'd rather want to do that once.

Comment: @Leonid: If you know in advance how many elements you need, then resize() is fine to use. However, if you don't, then push_back is the main option.

Comment: Leonid: you can use `push_back` efficiently if you first call `vector::reserve` to reserve space.

Comment: @DeadMG: but if you know the number of elements at the initialization time is there a reason to use resize? You can specify the size in the constructor to vector, as well as default element.

Comment: @Philip: Yes, surely you can, but why would you want to do it in 2 lines of code, if you can do the same with 1 line.

Comment: @DeadMG: in this case there is no advantage in using resize instead of the constructor, only disadvantages.

Comment: I think you could argue that calling a function which is clearly named is much better for a project in terms of human readable code.

ie, using reserve or resize instead of the constructor

Answer (score 10):

Replace

```
freqnote[0] = 16.35;
```

with

```
freqnote.push_back(16.35);
```

and you'll be fine.

The error is due to that index being out-of-range. At the time of your accessing the first element via `[0]`, the vector likely has a capacity of 0. `push_back()`, on the other hand, will expand the vector's capacity (if necessary).

Answer (score 7):

You can't initialise an element in a vector like that.

You have to go:

```
freqnote.push_back(16.35),
```

then access it as you would an array

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, it's an issue about inserting an out of range index in the `vector`.

A `vector` is a dynamically sized array, it begins with a size of 0 and you can then extend/shrink it at your heart content.

There are 2 ways of accessing a `vector` element by index:

- `vector::operator[](size_t)` (Experts only)
- `vector::at(size_t)`

(I dispensed with the `const` overloads)

Both have the same semantics, however the second is "secured" in the sense that it will perform bounds checking and throw a `std::out_of_range` exception in case you're off bound.

I would warmly recommend performing **ALL** accesses using **at**.

The performance penalty can be shrugged off for most use cases. The `operator[]` should only be used by experts, after they have profiled the code and this spot proved to be a bottleneck.

Now, for inserting new elements in the `vector` you have several alternatives:

- `push_back` will append an element
- `insert` will insert the element in front of the element pointed to by the `iterator`

Depending on the semantics you wish for, both are to be considered. And of course, both will make the `vector` grow appropriately.

Finally, you can also define the size explicitly:

- `vector(size_t n, T const& t = T())` is an overload of the constructor which lets you specify the size
- `resize(size_t n, T const& t = T())` allows you to resize the vector, appending new elements if it gets bigger than it was

Both method allow you to supply an element to be copied (exemplar) and default to copying a default constructed object (`0` if `T` is an `int`) if you don't supply the exemplar explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using push_back() to store new elements, you can also call resize() once before you start using the vector to specify the number of elements it contains. This is very similar to allocating an array.